# SSIS - Script Component for Date Formatting - VB.NET/C#

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, ssis

so I have a situation where (via SSIS) I'm basically running a SELECT against my DB, and then exporting the results to a .txt flatfile.

The SSIS flow is as follows: OLEDB SOURCE (my select query) -> DATA CONVERSION (change all values to DT_WSTR) -> FLAT FILE DESTINATION

However, I was told I need to change the format of all the datetime column values I export from the format of `yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss` (what it is in the DB) to `mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss AM/PM`

From my searching on this topic, I believe a script component between my DATA CONVERSION and FLAT FILE DESTINATION is what I need in SSIS....but I have no VB.NET or C# skills whatsoever.  And despite searching, I have yet to really understand how I'd code this date formatting conversion up.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the conversion in your SELECT statement.

This will get your close:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GetDate(),101) + ' ' 
+ LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(26),GetDate(),9),14))
```

Just replace GetDate() with your date field.  If you need it without the nanoseconds, it's a bit longer:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GetDate(),101) + ' ' 
+ LTRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(26),GetDate(),9),14),8)) + ' ' 
+ RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(26),GetDate(),9),2)
```

Comment: I always find it dissapointing that SQL hasn't built something something similar to .net ToString("mm/dd/yyyy hh:MM:ss")

Comment: Rejoice, the 2012 release of SQL Server provides access to the .NET string formatters.